# send() socket working on C but Java read from the bufferedReader doesn't get response

Tags: java, c, sockets, char, communication

I have a particular problema, here is the code

```
void sendThread(struct List* list){
bool listening = true;
char sent[1024] = "";
while(listening){
    sleep(5);
    strcat(sent,list2String(&list));
    printf("%s\n", sent);
    for(int i = 0; i<amountInArr;i++){
        send(client[i],(const void*)sent,strlen(sent),0);
    }
    memset(sent,0,1024);
}
```

The thing is that send() does work and returns the amount of bytes sent through the socket, this is connected to a client that is written on Java, but when I try to receive what's on the socket, reader.ReadLine() from Java never catches a thing, but the tricky thing comes here if I do this:

```
void sendThread(){
bool listening = true;
char sent[1024];
while(listening){
    printf("Please enter your message\n");
    fgets(sent,1024,stdin);
    printf("This is the message: %s\n", sent);
    for(int i = 0; i<amountInArr;i++){
        send(client[i],sent,strlen(sent),0);
    }
}
```

The code works perfectly and it communicates with Java with no errors, whats the difference between getting the char* to send from a user input and building it from a function and sending it?

The code I'm using to build the char* is the next one:

```
char* list2String(struct List* lista){
char* charToSend = malloc(sizeof(char)*1024);
char tmp[256];
struct Node* current = lista->head->next->next;
while(current != NULL){
    sprintf(tmp, "%d,%d,%d,%d,%d_", current->data.x,current->data.y,current->data.type,current->data.vel,current->data.dir);
    strcat(charToSend,tmp);
    current = current->next;
}
strcat(charToSend,"@");
sprintf(tmp,"%d_%d@%d_%d_%d@%d_%d_%d_%d@%d,%d_%d,%d_%d,%d",puntuacion,vidas,playerX,playerY,5,bulletPosX,bulletPosY,10,10,1,b1L,2,b2L,3,b3L);
strcat(charToSend,tmp);
memset(tmp,0,256);
return charToSend;
```

I'm thinking that it has something to do with formats or how does fgets() manages data different from the list2String.

I would be very happy if someone could help me figure this out, thank you!

Comment: *send() socket working on C* How do you know it's working?  You don't check the returned value.

Comment: I did check the returned value and it is different from -1, it returns 825 and thats the amount of bytes sent through the socket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual. You are reading lines but you aren't sending lines. Add a line terminator to the sent data.

Comment: Mmm...What's a line terminator? Can you be more specific please?

Comment: The line terminator in C, including a `sprintf()` format string, is `\n`. This is rather basic.

Comment: Thank You! It worked, sorry i didn't know that

Comment: I think you're a little too quick in closing this as a dupe.  `char* charToSend = malloc(sizeof(char)*1024);` and `strcat(charToSend,tmp);` means that `strcat()` causes UB.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Oh sure, and there is also a memory leak ... everything that could go wrong is wrong. But he isn't asking about a SIGSEGV, or a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was stumped, I'm pretty new at this, I appreciate your responses!